# ClassNotFoundException in a shaded jar

Tags: maven, javafx, java-8, classnotfoundexception, javaagents

I'm trying to launch the java agent i have generated by getting the sources here : https://github.com/1C-Company/FxDriver

However, i have somes troubles to make it work. I get this error when i start my javafx application with the generated shaded jar as java agent :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/grid/internal/utils/configuration/StandaloneConfiguration
        at com._1c.qa.selenium.fxdriver.FxServer.lambda$start$0(FxServer.java:28)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.configuration.StandaloneConfiguration
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 2 more
```

My javafx application start but obviously, not my agent associated.

When i look in the shaded jar, the class missing (StandaloneConfiguration) is present with the good path in the shaded jar which i have generated by using git bash with the following maven command : `mvn clean install`

I don't really understand (after looking for quite some times for similar things) where is exactly the problem.

Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and how it helps you get spot-on answers to your questions by making your problem reproducible. For example, you did not explain what is inside the shaded JAR, how exactly you shaded it (One-JAR with nested JARs, Assembly or Maven Shade with exploded JARs), how you start your application (`-javaagent ...`?). I need more information to analyze your problem. A sample Maven project on GitHub would be perfect.

Comment: The pom of the sources is accessible here : https://github.com/1C-Company/FxDriver/blob/master/pom.xml, when i make a maven clean install, one shaded jar, and a normal one is generated. For the -javaagent, here a example of the call : -javaagent:C:\Users\...\.m2\...\fxdriver-0.2-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar=port=9999

Comment: That looks like the tool that you are using, thanks. I want to see your own application (or a minimal, abstracted version of it, reproducing the problem) which uses that FxDriver tool.

Comment: Sadly, the application is too complexe to be simplified and posted online. But i don't get it, the problem could come from my application ? Seems like she run well but fxdriver fail to start on his own.

Comment: Of course it can come from your application. Besides, "too complex to be simplified" is just a lame excuse, with all due respect. Just a simple shaded JAR with a dummy app, one or two packaged dependencies and one Selenium test as a Maven project in order to reproduce the problem. Are you a developer or not?

Comment: The application have something like 300 000 lines of codes. I'm a new comer so i don't know how everything work in this app. I'm just trying to add somes functional test automatized. And the problems occur before launching any selenium test.